# Output redirection to file using subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a program script.out which I need to run against 10 files and redirect their output to 10 files.
I am using `subprocess.Popen()` for this work but it seems to catch some error when redirecting stdout stream.

```py
...
for i in range(10):
   data = subprocess.Popen([ script.out, "<", input_file[i], ">", output_file[i]])
```

For the workaround, I use `os.system()` to run directly. But I want to know why the `subprocess.Popen()` process failed there?

Comment: I was getting multiple errors like ```terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  cannot create std::vector larger than max_size()``` and I don't catch any error while running that command from shell manually. The script.out file is working fine

Comment: Why on Earth would you ever do this over the standard file operations?

Comment: I guess I am stupid @JaredSmith . But really wanna know the main catch here

Comment: `with open(some_file_path, "w") as file_handle: file_handle.write(some_data)`

Comment: I know it can be done like that. But why this is messing up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O redirection with `<` and `>` is done by the shell. When you call `subprocess.Popen()` with a list as the first argument or without `shell=True`, the program is executed directly, not using the shell to parse the command line. So you're executing the program and passing literal arguments `<` and `>` to it. It's as if you executed the shell command and quoted the `<` and `>` characters:

```
scriptname '<' infile.txt '>' outfile.txt
```

If you want to use the shell you have to send a single string (just like using `os.system()`.

```
data = subprocess.Popen(" ".join([ shlex.quote(script.out), "<", shlex.quote(input_file[i]), ">", shlex.quote(output_file[i])]), shell=True)
```

Use `shlex.quote()` to escape arguments that shouldn't be treated as shell metacharacters.

Comment: So `<` and `>` will be treated as arguments for the scriptFile?

Comment: using `shell=True`  didn't work as well for me

Comment: Did you combine everything into a single string, instead of using a list?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Using '<' or '>' in `subprocess.Popen` arguments without passing `shell=True` will not have any effect, because input redirection is a feature of shells. Passing `shell=True` does have some security considerations if you deal with untrusted data though (namely shell injection), so I don't advise going that route for this particular task of yours. You can read more here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations

The simple solution for your task would be to use a `stdout` parameter on creation of `subprocess.Popen` object:

```
import subprocess

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    p = subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/executable', 'arg1'], stdout=f)
```

Reference from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

> stdin, **stdout** and stderr specify the executed program’s standard input, **standard output** and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, **an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object**, and None. PIPE indicates that a new pipe to the child should be created. DEVNULL indicates that the special file os.devnull will be used. With the default settings of None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent. Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT, which indicates that the stderr data from the applications should be captured into the same file handle as for stdout.